# split string value but keep the line break inside new array

Tags: javascript, regex, split, line-breaks

I want keep the line breaks after I do some logic in my string value for a textarea element. Lets say I have this string from my textarea:

```
"Test

Newline here"
```

array: `["Test\nNewline", "here"]`

How can I save it to be like this: `["Test", "\n", "Newline", "here"]`

My code:

```
let bodyText = "Test

Newline here"

let bodyTextArray = bodyText.split(/ |\n|(?=\n)/g)
```

Basically what is happening it it is splitting and removing the spaces and "\n". using positive lookahead isn't working, I was trying with negative look ahead with no success.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this

```
let bodyText = "Test
Newline here"
let bodyTextArray = bodyText.split(/( |\n)/)
```

If you put capturing `()` around what you are splitting on then that is added to the output

Comment: This doesn't seem to give the output the OP requested.  But it's been marked as accepted.!!

Answer (score 3):

You can match those:

```js
let bodyText = `Test

Newline here`
let bodyTextArray = bodyText.match(/^\n|\S+/gm)
console.log(bodyTextArray)
```

*Details*:

- `^\n` - start of a line and a newline
- `|` - or
- `\S+` - any one or more non-whitespace chars.

To support CRLF, LF or CR line endings, use

```js
/^(?:\r\n?|\n)|\S+/gm
```

where `(?:\r\n?|\n)` replaced `\n` and matches either a CR and an optional LF char, or just an LF char.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a split using this regex:

```
/(\n)+|\s+/
```

**Code:**

```js
const input = `Test

Newline here`;

var arr = input.split(/(\n)+|\s+/);

console.log(arr.filter(Boolean));
```

**Explanation:**

- `/(\n)+|\s+/` splits input on 1+ newlines while capturing a single newline (to make `\n` available in output array after split) or 1+ whitespace
- `.filter(Boolean)` removes empty or undefined entries from array